# how do i prepare training set for a set of images? so that i can predict my test data

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification

I have extracted all the features say about 15 features,for medical images,now i need to classify them as Normal (0) or abnormal (1). how can i prepare training data for these images? I tried using ground truth for testing data, is it the right way of doing it?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about. To train a model, you need to have labeled data (0 or 1, in your case) and the features, which you have. What part is confusing? Do you not know how to train a model generally, or is there something about this particular case that's confusing you?

Comment: There are lots of steps involved in preparing training data.Please be more specific.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use neural networks(convolutional neural networks to be more precisely ) , the pixels themselves are the features so the preparations(pre-processing) its just related to things like:

- Resolution reduction
- Artificial data creation from original training set(adding some distortions , reflections, and variations to the original data)
- Normalization(to get almost 0 mean and low variance) for example, if your data is one channel depth(greyscale) ranging from 0 to 255, you can do something like:
  data = (data - Mean(data))/255